# Velocity : Breaking out of foreach-loop dynamically

Tags: velocity

i need to implement a solution in Velocity for breaking out of a foreach-loop at the **forelast** item of the array. With the API i came to build this, but i doesnt break out and still shows all rows of the loop.
Does anyone have a better or working approach for me?

```
«#if($special)»
  «#foreach($item in $sum)»
    «#if($foreach.hasNext==false)» «#break» «#end»
    «do special stuff» 
  «#end»
«#else»
  «#foreach($item in $sum)»
    «do normal stuff»
  «#end»
«#end»
```

Comment: look like your condition wrong `$foreach.hasNext==false` here .

Comment: found it like this in the official API :(

Answer (score 1):

```
#if(!$foreach.hasNext) #break #end
```

or

```
#if($foreach.hasNext == false) #break #end
```

should both work for Velocity 1.7+. If you have some doubt about it, you can display

```
$foreach.hasNext
```

in the loop and check that it prints `true true true ... false`.

For prior versions of Velocity, you would have to do it yourself:

```
#set($count = $num.size())
#foreach($item in $num)
  #if($velocityCount < $count)
    ...
  #end
#end
```

Note that the `$velocityCount` variable (which was deprecated in 1.7 and disappeared in 2.0) starts at 1.